# PDF Generation library supporting gradient fills

Tags: pdf-generation

Are there any libraries out there (python, .net, c++, anything...) that can generate PDF libraries that also includes features like gradient shading?

Answer (score 2):

[iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) [can](http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/directcontent/colors/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different types of gradient fills: linear, radial etc.

What kind of effect are you hoping to achieve?

Quick PDF Library supports only linear (axial) gradients:
http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/help/quickpdf/NewRGBAxialShader.php

Answer (score 0):

[PDFSharp http://www.pdfsharp.com/](http://www.pdfsharp.com/) seems capable.  See [example pdf](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/images/stories/samples/PDFs/Graphics.pdf):